# Pinning desktops to monitors in 10.9

Tags: macos, desktop, mission-control

Is there a way to pin desktops to monitors like you can pin app windows to desktops?

Specifically my problem is I use a macbook and plug and unplug my external monitor a few times a day. Rearranging my desktops and full-screen apps every time is a pain in the rear end and so I hope there's a setting for that that I just can't find.

Answer (score -2):

There was a way to do this a few years ago. I think it was on SL with some third party software, but sadly I can't remember what it was called. Could be discontinued though...

Edit: I remembered: Put the app to the desktop where you want to have it. Right click on dock icon, go to options and select the space you want to assign the app to.

Comment: This is what works for assigning apps to spaces (they're called desktops now). I want to do a similar thing with the whole space - assign it to a monitor. With mavericks spaces don't span monitors anymore.

Comment: Oh ok, I misunderstood that... I experienced that similar with VLC on an external AirPlay Monitor. When I remember right, if I first quit the app, then disconnect the monitor it will start again on the monitor next time. Of course, you'll need the connect the monitor before starting the app next time.

Otherwise there would be apps on desktops on an external monitor which isn't even connected. That seems difficult ^^

Have you tried to do what I said in my edit: Assigning a desktop of the external monitor to an app?

Comment: Yeah, quitting and only starting when the monitor is back works, but I was hoping for something like an auto detection of when the monitor is present, because I can hardly quit a whole desktop, when unplugging the screen

Comment: I'm afraid there is no other way, but maybe someone's got some third party software to do that...

Comment: I'm not ready to admit defeat yet, but I might be so

Comment: Check out slate - https://github.com/jigish/slate - I think it has the ability to change the workspace when a new monitor gets plugged in. In the worst case scenario you can just create a keyboard shortcut and it will rearrange everything for you!